# Function calling wrong class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use an intent to start two different classes in which I change either the text size or text colour of an entered message. Starting these classes is triggered by two different button push events in android studio. However, only the TextSize class is being started no matter what button I push and I cannot see the reason why. Below I have the problem activities class code and xml code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public static final String EXTRAA_MESSAGE ="message2";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


public void changeText(View v){
    EditText messageView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
    String messageText = messageView.getText().toString();
    Intent result = new Intent(this, TextSize.class);
    result.putExtra("message",messageText);
    startActivity(result);
}

public void changeColour(View v){
    EditText messageView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
    String messageText = messageView.getText().toString();
    Intent result = new Intent(this, ColourChange.class);
    result.putExtra("message",messageText);
    startActivity(result);
}
```

My XML File

```
    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Change Colour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Colour"
        android:onClick="changeColour"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:onClick="changeText"
        android:text="Change Text Size"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Colour"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Colour"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
        android:id="@+id/TextSize" />
```

Comment: past complete xml file.

Comment: Intent result = new Intent have you tried to give it different name for Intent, for example try resultText and resultColor?

Answer (score 0):

In Android just implements the `OnClickListener` for you when you define the `android:onClick="someMethod"` attribute.

you can implemented just different way.

```
Button btnColour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Colour);

btnColour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      // call your method here
      changeColour(v);
  }
});

// your method code

public void changeColour(View v) {
    // your method code
}
```

As You doing 
check your xml file that have you define context with parent layout or not

```
tools:context="com.example.YourActivity"
```

// com.example.YourActivity should be your activity with package name